# Navigating to existing view model

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, caliburn.micro

Normally I would use a generic for navigation:

```
navigationService
    .UriFor<PivotPageViewModel>()  
    .Navigate();
```

But how do I do if I have an existing view model instance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checking the source reveals this in `UriBuilder`

```
public Uri BuildUri() 
{
    var viewType = ViewLocator.LocateTypeForModelType(typeof(TViewModel), null, null);

    if(viewType == null) 
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException(string.Format("No view was found for {0}. See the log for searched views.", typeof(TViewModel).FullName));
    }

    var packUri = ViewLocator.DeterminePackUriFromType(typeof(TViewModel), viewType);
    var qs = BuildQueryString();

    return new Uri(packUri + qs, UriKind.Relative);
}
```

So you either use GetType on `navigationService` and use reflection `MakeGenericMethod` using the type of the VM:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.methodinfo.makegenericmethod.aspx

Or you could use the code above, replacing the `typeof` calls with a `viewModel.GetType()` (but you will have to rewrite BuildQueryString on UriBuilder as it's private - go with option 1!)

The choice is yours!